# How to get probabilities along with classification in LogisticRegression?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, multiclass-classification

I am using Logistic regression algorithm for multi-class text classification. I need a way to get the confidence score along with the category. For eg - 
If I pass text = "Hello this is sample text" to the model, I should get **predicted class = Class A and confidence = 80%** as a result.

Comment: Scikit-learn classifiers will give you the class prediction through their `predict()` method. If you want the probability estimates, use `predict_proba()`. You can easily transform the latter into the former by applying a threshold: if the predicted probability is larger than 0.50, predict the positive class. See https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict_proba

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For most models in scikit-learn, we can get the probability estimates for the classes through [`predict_proba`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict_proba). Bear in mind that this is the actual output of the logistic function, the resulting classification is obtained by selecting the output with highest probability, i.e. an `argmax` is applied on the output. If we see the implementation [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/fd237278e/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py#L293), you can see that it is essentially doing:

```
def predict(self, X):
    # decision func on input array
    scores = self.decision_function(X)
    # column indices of max values per row
    indices = scores.argmax(axis=1)
    # index class array using indices
    return self.classes_[indices]
```

In the case of calling `predict_proba` rather than `predict`, `scores` is returned. Here's an example use case training a [`LogisticRegression`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict_proba):

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

lr= LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred_prob = lr.predict_proba(X_test)

y_pred_prob
array([[1.06906558e-02, 9.02308167e-01, 8.70011771e-02],
       [2.57953117e-06, 7.88832490e-03, 9.92109096e-01],
       [2.66690975e-05, 6.73454730e-02, 9.32627858e-01],
       [9.88612145e-01, 1.13878133e-02, 4.12714660e-08],
       ...
```

And we can obtain the probabilities by taking the `argmax`, as mentioned, and index the array of classes as:

```
classes = load_iris().target_names
classes[indices]
array(['virginica', 'virginica', 'versicolor', 'virginica', 'setosa',
       'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'setosa', 'virginica', 'setosa',...
```

So for a single prediction, through the predicted probabilities we could easily do something like:

```
y_pred_prob = lr.predict_proba(X_test[0,None])
ix = y_pred_prob.argmax(1).item()

print(f'predicted class = {classes[ix]} and confidence = {y_pred_prob[0,ix]:.2%}')
# predicted class = virginica and confidence = 90.75%
```